# How to restrict find-tag-regexp to search only the symbol part of TAGS

Tags: ctags

A typical line in a `TAGS` file looks like this (note use of special characters `^?` and `^A`)

```
(defvar copyright-owner user-full-name^?copyright-owner^A213,7296
```

and a `find-tag-regexp` will search the entire line. But I want to restrict my searches to just the 2nd column, i.e. `copyright-owner`. In particular, for this example I want to avoid false positives for searches of `user-full-name` from finding this entry.

How can I restrict `find-tag-regexp` to just the matching part of the line and not the whole line?

Format defined in more detail here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags#Etags_2

Comment: You can try advising `tag-re-match-p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ouch, it looks like `find-tag` explicitly only searches the first column and never looks at the tag itself. That's nasty.

From `etags-tags-completion-table`

```
  ;; This monster regexp matches an etags tag line.
  ;;   \1 is the string to match;
  ;;   \2 is not interesting;
  ;;   \3 is the guessed tag name; XXX guess should be better eg DEFUN
  ;;   \4 is not interesting;
  ;;   \5 is the explicitly-specified tag name.
  ;;   \6 is the line to start searching at;
  ;;   \7 is the char to start searching at.
```

To bypass this issue entirely, I now use etags-select.

Comment: That's a wrong interpretation. `\1` is just a big group, I don't know why it's called "string to match", but this function has been simplified a lot in the current development tree.

Comment: Anyway, this function just extracts the "completion" table, which only affects the suggestions for available tags, not the `find-tag-regexp` logic.